# HTML elements being misplaced while loading view within another view in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view

I have called a view within another view

```
    <!-- right area ends -->
        </div><!--row marginTR-30px ends-->

</div><!--container marg-top-bnr ends-->
<!-- blog area ends -->


<?php $this->load->view('common/footer'); ?>
<?php $this->common_lib->compared_salon();  ?>


</div><!--body-inner salon-profile ends -->
<a href="#"class="top-move">Top</a>
```

Here I have rendered my view **footer** after these element and html comment

```
<!-- right area ends -->
            </div><!--row marginTR-30px ends-->

    </div><!--container marg-top-bnr ends-->
    <!-- blog area ends -->
```

But when it's loaded, the entire element available inside the footer view goes to some of its parent element as I'm able to see it with inspect element

[Click here to see it in large view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEhLT.png)

[image]

All social icons are horizontally aligned, but due to tag structure change while loading view, its look is totally changed.

Earlier it's running well, I'm unable to find solution. According to me all footer tag element should come after these line, but it's showing before it.

```
<!-- right area ends -->
                </div><!--row marginTR-30px ends-->

        </div><!--container marg-top-bnr ends-->
        <!-- blog area ends -->
```

Comment: why are you loading a view inside another view?

Comment: that is the requrirement. I have rendered three view in controller, 1: before.php 2: content.php, 3: after.php, and I'm also rending the footer.php inside the after.php

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have not shown any of the HTML associated with your issue.

My educated guess is that your divs are "up the spout". I'd be looking at the actual HTML Source and making sure your   pairs are where you expect them to be.

If you "had it working" and now it's not - it's very easy to have this happen (read as - I've done this myself on the odd occassion ).

UPDATE:
So out of all that code you provided, I found

```
<div class="marginT-30px social clearfix">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/salontrip" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 fb height-Socl" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 pin height-Socl"></a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 twit height-Socl"></a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 yout height-Socl"></a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 linkd height-Socl"></a>
    <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 googplus height-Socl"></a>
</div>
```

I'm Not sure if 6 x 4 is ever equal to 12! :)
I'd be going over that code with a fine tooth comb. I've no idea what or where marginT-30px and friends are set.

Comment: Are they meant to be so "huge"? They seem to be overly large! Are you sure you've got the right CSS style/id around them?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/91vvpcx8/ this is footer view. I have rendered this one inside the after view